# Authenticate user by custom pin to access keystore

Tags: android, security, authentication, keystore

I am generating key pair via KeyPairGenerator initialized with KeyGenParameterSpec that requires user authentication to access private key by setting `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)`.

When using fingerprint or biometric authentication, it is possible to delegate the authentication to system dialogs through `BiometricPrompt`.

Is there a possibility to authenticate user to access keystore's protected keys by implementing own PIN dialog? The system allows device-pin authentication, but in such case the pin is not dependent on app but on the whole device and cannot be customized.

Is there any Android API I am missing to authenticate user for Keystore access?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @DanailAlexiev No, I couldn't find any solution